# How can i save multiple section details in asp.net mvc3 page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on asp.net mvc3 application, in this i have user profile section this having many sections like general details, education, work and many...

Now my issue is i want user to insert their information and on click of add i want to display inserted information in another section and on click of save i want to insert all information into database.

Like,

Education Section::
In this user can fill their school details, college details.

**School**

```
School Division: Dropdown

School Name: Textbox

School Branch: Textbox

School Year: Dropdown

***Add School***
```

**College**

```
College Division: Dropdown

CollegeName: Textbox

CollegeBranch: Textbox

CollegeYear: Dropdown

***Add College***

     **SAVE CANCEL**
```

I have this in my education section,
when user click on add school i want entered data display into another section and when user click on save button all data should go into database, so that we can reduce database roundtrip fo saving details on 1 click.
User can enter multiple schools and colleges in their profile.

My question is,

how can i display entered data into another section/div?

what is the best way to do this thing so that when user click on save button my code will fetch all entered data and saving data into database?

I tried this to display information entered on add school click but in this i am not able to get details back for saving.

```
function addSchool() {

var result = document.getElementById('schoolDiv').innerHTML + "</br>" + "<br/>School: " + document.getElementById('schooldiv').value + "<br/>School Name: " + document.getElementById('schoolname').value +"<br/>Branch: " + document.getElementById('branch').value + "<br/>School Year: " + document.getElementById('schoolyear').value;

                document.getElementById('schoolDiv').innerHTML = result;
}
```

What is the best way to do so in asp.net mvc3?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have only one problem, which is to extract the values already entered and display them in another format, almost like a running summary.

Firstly, I would highly recommend that you use a JavaScript library such as jQuery, which will take out all the heavy lifting of extracting and redisplaying values. You could also use the jQuery UI tabs plugin to handle the sections problem: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Writing it yourself, there are various approaches you could take to redisplaying the entered data. One simple approach would be to have a Summary template, with its own sections, for example:

```
<div id="summary">
    <div id="personalSummary" style="display: none;">
        <p>Various elements to hold summary</p>
    </div>
    <div id="educationSummary" style="display: none;">
        <p>Various elements to hold summary</p>
    </div>
</div>
<form>
<div id='sections'>
    <div id="personal">
        <input type="button" value="Next" />
    </div>
    <div id="education" style="display: none;">
        <input type="button" value="Next" />
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

So what you need now is some JavaScript that when they click on each button it extracts the values for that section and plugs them into the summary section and displays it. I can't show you how to do all of that but using the jQuery val function it would be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function completeSection(sectionId) {
        var section = $('#' + sectionId);
        var summary = $('#' + sectionId + 'Summary');
        // swap a value over.
        var value = $('#firstName', section).val();
        $('#firstNameSummary', summary).val(value);
        // etc

        // now hide the input section, display the summary section and move the
        // the whole summary to the next input section
        section.hide();
        summary.show();
        $('#summary').prependTo($('#education'));
    }
</script>
```

Note that the above is just a sketch of the idea. The idea is that you keep updating the summary, showing the updated section, hiding the data just input, then moving the summary box to the top of the next section.

When they click the final save button, although your sections are hidden, the will still get submitted.

Answer (score 0):

One easy alternative us to simply do an Ajax save when they add a new section/ for example they click to add a new school, save the prior section or simply put a save button next to each section and when they finish each section they click save which does an ajax call to save only the recent changes.  This would be accomplished using a jQuery .Ajax() call.